# How to use PendingIntent in android widgets?

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, onclick, widget, android-widget

I'm still a noob and can't find solution just by documentation. I have a widget with view as a button and need to start activity when view is clicked.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/config"
    android:paddingLeft="14dp" android:paddingTop="3dp" android:paddingBottom="3dp" android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  android:background="@drawable/config_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true" android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:text="..." android:rotation="90" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:clickable="true" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I know that simple Intent, PendingIntent and setOnClickPendingIntent() in widgets doesnt work and I must somehow use setPendingIntentTemplate() together with setOnClickFillInIntent(), but I don't know how.

For now I have this, which of course doesn't work yet:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConfigActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.ror_appwidget);

        views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.config, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

What I'm missing here and how should I use the setOnClickFillInIntent method? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you ONLY use setOnClickFillInIntent ALONG with setPendingIntentTemplate when you have a ListView on your widget and want to handle clicks on a ListView item. But this is not your case.

I'll give you a small example on how to achieve the simple click event on your button and open an activity.

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews views = buildRemoteViews(context);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views);
        }
    }

    private RemoteViews buildRemoteViews(Context context) {
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
        homeIntent.setData(Uri.parse(homeIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent homePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, homeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.your_button, homePendingIntent);

        return views;
    }
}
```

This should be enough code for your needs.

Very important though is to declare your widget in the manifest file:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".ui.widget.WidgetProvider"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="MyWidgetSample">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED" />
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_provider_info"/>
    </receiver>
```

Your widget info provider file(widget_provider_info.xml) in the res/xml folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/layout_widget"<!-- your built layout for the widget-->
    android:minHeight="110dp"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen" />
```

Does this help?

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: Yep, problem was that I forgot to add the activity in manifest.

Comment: I see. Good luck further on!

Comment: how to use `setPendingIntentTemplate` ?